# How can I replace dotnet core System.Random in implementation with my random class for all my application?

Tags: c#, random, .net-core, hook, code-injection

I have a dotnet core console application that uses System.Random.I do not have the code for that application but I want to replace the calls to the Random methods with my specific random implementation.
I created a StartupHook, but I miss the method to replace the System.Random code with mine
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe try an IL Weaver to re-write the dll or exe you've been given to replace calls to Random with your own IL code? It's a little hairy, but when you're talking about changing the behavior of an app you don't own the code for, you can expect hairy.

Comment: Just bear in mind, using ILWeaver or reverse engineering the code *may or may not* violate either the license provided by the third party, or local laws.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have code or the code doesnt allow you to swap Random Class implementation you dont have much luck. When you say you dont have code, are referring to DLL or exe?

If it is your or your company DLL you can try to decompile it and modify the code and recompile. It will be like new version.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response.
The code is a 3rd party dll, so unfortunately I do not have access to the code.